# Trouble parsing bundler's conflict output message

Tags: bundler

I'm getting

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
  some_gem was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
    devise (>= 3.2.4, < 4.0.0) was resolved to 3.5.10, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)

  some_gem was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
    rails (~> 4.0.13) was resolved to 4.0.13, which depends on
      railties (= 4.0.13)

  rspec-rails (~> 3.8) was resolved to 3.8.2, which depends on
    railties (>= 3.0)
```

Doesn't `railties = 4.0.13` satisfy all 3 `railties` version conditions?

Answer (score 0):

At least, Devise requires railties (">= 4.1.0", "< 6.0"), as you can see here. 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plataformatec/devise/master/devise.gemspec

So you can try specifying the version in your Gemfile:
  gem 'railties', '~> 4.1.0'

Comment: That won't work because `railties (= 4.0.13)` wouldn't be satisfied, right?

Comment: You can update Rails to 5+ it should work, or are you stuck with that version?

Comment: My point is trying to understand the versioning conditions that Bundler uses to match requirements. It makes sense that the example posted should work.

Comment: Here is a concise explanation http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/9/24/how-does-bundler-bundle
As you stated, it makes sense, but can you share your Gemfile?