# Semantic versioning in rails: is 6.1.0.alpha considered greater than 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, semantic-versioning

What's the problem here? 6.1.0.alpha is greater than 5.2 so I don't know why my bundle/build is failing on travis ci.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    rails was resolved to 6.1.0.alpha, which depends on
      activemodel (= 6.1.0.alpha)
    web-console was resolved to 3.7.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 5.2)
```

Comment: I answered a similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813658/trouble-parsing-bundlers-conflict-output-message/55815199?noredirect=1#comment98298546_55815199
can you share your Gemfile?

Comment: Is this the only error? Bundler tends to output all version requirements for gems it cannot match versions of, even those that are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it like this:

```rb
Gem::Version.new('6.1.0.alpha') >= Gem::Version.new('5.2') # => true
Gem::Requirement.new(">= 5.2").satisfied_by?(Gem::Version.new('6.1.0.alpha')) # => true
```

Bundler tends to output all version requirements for gems it cannot match versions of, even those that are satisfied, most probably there's another gem with unmatched requirements.